# Angular 2 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:

Tags: javascript, angular

Basically this is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div [hidden]="loggedIn">
<md-grid-list cols="6" [style.margin-top]="'20px'">
<md-grid-tile [colspan]="1"></md-grid-tile>
```

And I have already added the md-input-container for instance into my style.css file. When I ran my Angular 2 in terminal it said compile successfully. But when I open my chrome to see the actual website. It does have errors shown below:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>     Can't bind to 'colspan' since it isn't a known property of 'md-grid-tile'.
>     1. If 'md-grid-tile' is an Angular component and it has 'colspan' input, then `verify that 
>     it is part of this module.
>     2. If 'md-grid-tile' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to 
>     the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: Hi Stan! If you rephrase your opening statement (1st line) into a question - with a question mark - then your issue might attract more attention from the main page. Otherwise, it looks like you're stuck debugging & struggling with the code, which is what we all go through as developers. People will tend to ask things like: "What is your question?" It would also help if you could create a JSFiddle.net example of what you're trying to do. Then once people can recreate the issue, then they can play around with the code to help you figure it out. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it as, otherwise it will take it as a input property which you need to declare inside the component

```
<md-grid-tile colspan="1"></md-grid-tile>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enter

> [colspan]="1"

It expects a variable from the component, what you need is

> colspan="1"

Comment: it didn't worked for two other bugs... 'mat-grid-tile' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-grid-tile' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: Then the issue is that you haven't properly imported MdGridModule in the app